# reading specific line from many csv files, python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to print out a specific row (row #5) from each of the many csv files I have in a particular folder. For some reason, it returns the correct 5th row for the first file, but then messes up on all the rest. I think it's working in some kind of loop, but I can't quite figure out why/what/how:

```
    for file in files:
        j = 1
        with open(file,'rU') as csvfile:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',', quotechar ='|')
            for row in csv_reader:
                if j is 5:
                    print row
                j += 1
```

Comment: `j is 5` is bad. Do `j == 5`. and what's the problem on the next files?

Comment: you should `break` when `j == 5`, because there's nothing else to do with the file.

Comment: Thanks to both you and Patrick. Just curious, why is `j is 5` bad?

Comment: `5` isn't guaranteed to be a singleton. `is` compares references, not values.

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in files:
    with open(file, newline='') as f:
        r = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',', quotechar ='|')
        for i, row in enumerate(r, start=1):
            if i == 5:
                print(row)
                break
```

Don't use `j is 5`.  Use `enumerate` over keeping track of a counter manually, it's harder to make mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I changed

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',', quotechar ='|')
```

to

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
```

and it magically worked...

Comment: Maybe you had some `|` in your data that you weren't taking into account?

Comment: How could I check that?

Comment: If you're on windows, open the file in a text editor and `Ctrl-F` for `|`.  If you're on linux you can `egrep '\|' filename` to see all the lines with a `|`